# Type error ' list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple' (line 6)

Tags: python

i am trying to predict next word in compose mail modal but I am getting above error:

```
sequences = list ()

for i in range(1, len(encoded)):
    sequence = encoded[i - 1:i + 1]
    sequences.append(sequence)
sequence

X, Y = sequences[:,0], sequences[:,1] # error on this line
X = np.expand_dims(X, 1)
Y = np.expand_dims(Y, 1)
```

Comment: `[:,0]` is not valid on a list.

Answer (score 0):

you can do slice like `sequences[:,0]`, if sequences is `ndarray` in `numpy`.

but `list` is not support that, you can use `[seq[0] for seq in sequences]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

As you've already figured out, the error is because of this line:

```
X, Y = sequences[:,0], sequences[:,1]
```

`sequences[:,0]` is not valid syntax. Here are a couple of things you might have meant to do:

`sequences[:0]` will return all elements up to `sequences[0]`, exclusive. So this would return an empty list in this case.

`sequences[0:]` will return all elements from `sequences[0]` to the end of the list, inclusive. In this case it would return `[1, 2, 3]`.

`sequences[0]` will of course return the first element of the list.

---

This is not causing the error, but be aware that naming variables with capital letters is bad convention. `X` and `Y` should be renamed to `x` and `y` to keep them consistent with the [generally accepted naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names) for variables and functions.